# How to get calender icon to display using Twitter bootsrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a date time picker in my **C# MVC** view, but the calender icon to the right of my input box doesn't appear.

I am following the example from [here](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

**Part of my view**

```
<script src="/Scripts/angular-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" >
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
        <script  data-main="/Scripts/main" src="~/Scripts/require.min.js"></script>


 <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append">
                           <input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP" type="text"/>
                        <span class="add-on">
                            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
                            </i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

I have tried explicitly stating the path of the glyphicons icon like the following which did not work:

```
   @iconSpritePath:     "/Content/bootsrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png";
```

I end up getting this error:

> The name 'iconSpritePath' does not exist

I also noticed that my Twitter bootsrap 3 class does not include the icon-calender class.

How to make calender icon appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official bootstrap documentation:

With the launch of Bootstrap 3, icons have been moved to a separate repository. This keeps the primary project as lean as possible, makes it easier for folks to swap icon libraries, and makes Glyphicons icon fonts more readily available to more people outside Bootstrap.

This is how you use it. The instructions are here: http://glyphicons.getbootstrap.com/

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks Saugat. Can you help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290138/using-twitter-bootsrap-3-how-to-get-moder-form-input-with-rounded-corners